# Calculate total due in php codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, billing

I have a small billing software written in php CodeIgniter. This is how i save values when i submit a payment

```
    <?php
    public function addPayment() {

    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $client_id = $this->input->post('client_id');
    $date = strtotime($this->input->post('date_from_addpayment'));
    $description = $this->input->post('description');
    $cash_pending = $this->input->post('cash_pending');
    $cash_recevied = $this->input->post('cash_recevied');

    $balance = $cash_pending - $cash_recevied;
    ?>
```

When each transaction occur I want to sum all the due of the client at that time and save it in balance table in MySQL. 
My PHPMySQL structure of payment column is as follow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELJrL.png

I just want when user ADD THE PAYMENT then balance due at that time display in this column.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjlWv.png

Comment: I see you're doing `$due = $cash_pending - $cash_received` but there is no semicolon at the end of statement. 

Secondly,
What is the result of your `$due = $cash_pending - $cash_received`?

Comment: @YashKaranke sir if i put 1000 in cash_pending and 500 in cash_received then $due = 500.

Comment: is your code working? what is the output of `$due`?

Comment: So you want to add the current amount due (code above) to the stored amount due in the database; and I'm guessing also changing the cash pending and cash received fields in the database?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, balance, due, cash_pending - all 3 field relates - refers to the same figure - the amount that is pending. What i believe is you need to restructure the code for a bit.

You need to have a table maintaining clients balance (like current one you have). Just u can remove cash_pending / due fields.

You then need to have another table that will record in transactions of all the cash received. And as and when the cash is received, you can just substract that amount from the balance for the client.

In case any excess amount needs to be added for something like cash given or so - that you can add to the clients balance field back. So all the time - you have a proper balance figure for the client and also have a record of all the cash received from the user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all before ending the php tag close your function's curly bracket.

In your table id is auto increment so do not need to take id as a input to store in database.

put all required fields as your table structure like this.

```
$data = array('client_id'=>$client_id, 'date'=>$date,

 'description'=>$description, 'cash_recevied'=>$cash_recevied, 'cash_pending'=>$cash_pending,

 'due'=>$due  );

$this->load->model('Your-model-name');

$this->your-model-name->function-name($data);
```

Now call your model. and then in your model do this

```
function FunctionName($data){ 

return $this->db->insert('tablename', $data);

}
```